# AutocompleteInput shows current value as first suggestion

Tags: react-admin

On the [demo](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/), click on any order in `Pending orders`, then type something on the Customer field. You get the correct suggestions, so select one. Now go back and start typing another name. The input shows the previous selected suggestion on top of the suggestion list, regardless if it matches if the new text.
Is this the expected behaviour? And can it be configured somehow?

Comment: post some code or else I will suggest you to cross verify the states you set and make sure to empty the state when no result is found.

Comment: I don't think there is need for code, it's on the official demo. It looks intentional. My point was mostly to get the discussion going about if this is how it should work, because I don't think it is.